# Else statement never runs

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm having some trouble where my last `else` statement never runs even though I know the first `if` will eventually return false, any ideas?

```
if ($productType == 'HSweat' || 'T Shirt') {
    if ($productType == 'HSweat') {
        if (!$queryResult) {
        }
    } elseif ($productType == 'T Shirt') {
        if (!$queryResult) {
        }
    }
} else {
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if ($productType == 'HSweat' || 'T Shirt') {
```

Should be

```
if ($productType == 'HSweat' || $productType == 'T Shirt') {
```

'T Shirt' as a string will always evaluate to True

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `switch` :

```
switch( $productType ){
case 'HSweat':
     if (!$queryResult) {
         //Do something
     }
     break;
case 'T Shirt':         
     if (!$queryResult) {
         //Do something
     }
     break;
default:
     //Do something
     break;
}
```